# $.post retornar 2 valores

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho seguinte código:

```
 <script>

    $.post('http://localhost/app/user.php', {acao: acao}, function(retorna){ 

     $("#demo").html(retorna);

     if(retorna == "sucesso") {faça x}

    });

 </script>
```

Porém no `user.php` ele retorna vários `echo` dentros de condições `if`. Então se eu tenho no PHP, por exemplo, `echo "sucesso";` e outro `echo "sucesso";` ele retorna **sucessosucesso**.

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar cada um desse retorno separadamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resgatar cada informação desse retorno, utilize a função [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) e retornar somente um [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) para o seu [`Javascript`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript).

***Exemplo:***

```
$resposta['status'] = 'success';
$resposta['line'] = 1;

echo json_encode($resposta);
```

*Depois de executado esse* [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) *tem um formato* [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html):

```
{"status":"success","line":1}
```

*No retorno do seu javascript faça:*

[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
 <script>

    $.post('http://localhost/app/user.php', {acao: acao}, 
    function(retorna)
    { 

        if (retorna.status == 'success')
        {
           //faça alguma coisa 
        }

        if (retorna.line == 1)
        {
            //faça mais alguma coisa
        }
    },'json');

 </script>
```

Ou seja, retorna um *dado(s)* no formato [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html), para que o seu [Javascript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript), trabalhe com a informação de retorno. Também pode ser recebido uma [lista de informações](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/multidim-arrays.php).

**Referências:**

- [Trabalhando com JSON em PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-php/26716)
- [Pass PHP Arrays to JSON and JS with json_encode](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php)
- [Passing Multidimensional Arrays from PHP to JavaScript](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/multidim-arrays.php)
- [JSON with PHP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm)

Comment: João, eu fiz isso que que você passou e ele retornou no formato JSON: {"status":"success","line":1} porém eu não estou conseguindo pegar a condição no javascript com o retorna.status.

Comment: @rhundler  tenta assim > var dados = jQuery.parseJSON(retorna); depois dados.status

Comment: @rhundler faltou um configuração no seu javascript agora que vi, já fiz a edição! olha lá não precisa converter nada viu! No final da `function(retorna){}, 'json');` para que ele entenda que o retorno é um json

Comment: @rhundler `The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).` faltou especificar o retorno! link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. fiz a edição na minha resposta

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou perfeitamente após adicionar o 'json'. Obrigado!